# Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.ts(2589)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, internationalization, vue-i18n

I'm encountering an issue in my TypeScript code where I'm getting the error message "Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.ts(2589)" and I'm seeking guidance on resolving this issue.

Problem:

I have a Vue.js project with TypeScript where I'm using Vuetify for UI components and internationalization (i18n) for translations. I'm defining a table column in my Vue component and trying to access translation strings using the t function from i18n. However, TypeScript is throwing the error mentioned above, and I'm unsure how to address it.

test.ts file:

```
const { t } = i18n.global;
const hello = {
  label: t("helloworld"),
  // [Other properties and methods]
};
```

i18n file:

```
@imports:
const messages = {
  de: { ...deLib, ...deCur, $vuetify: de },
  en: { ...enLib, ...enCur, $vuetify: en },
}
export const i18n = createI18n({
  legacy: false,
  locale: "de",
  fallbackLocale: "de",
  messages,
  missingWarn: false,
  fallbackWarn: false,
  globalInjection: true,
  datetimeFormats: {
    de: {
      date: {
        year: "numeric",
        month: "2-digit",
        day: "2-digit",
      },
      dateTime: {
        year: "numeric",
        month: "2-digit",
        day: "2-digit",
        hour: "2-digit",
        minute: "2-digit",
      },
    },
  },
})

export const install = (app: any) => {
  app.use(i18n)

  const vuetify = createVuetify({
    components,
    directives,
    theme,
  })

  app.use(vuetify)
}
```